# Sql statement ((join?) to fetch result from multiple tables

Tags: sql, .net, ms-access, join

I am using Access database with VB.net.

I have 3 tables.

[image]

Now what i am looking forward is a result like this for any particular company i want.
Suppose if i am looking for Company1..this should be the result.If purchase has not bee made for a particular day..it should be blank..likewise in the case of payments also
[image]

How can i get this result using SQL Statement..

Comment: I have the solution but please tell me first, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I just know some simple Sql queries..This kind of join and union is out of my league..I am doing a project for myself and just got stuck with this..That's why i am asking it here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Full Outer Join. You can build an equivalent Full Outer join statement in MS Access by using multiple statements and Union (to remove duplicates)

I believe you can use something as follows:

```
SELECT a.Date, a.Gross, a.Net, a.Bonus, b.Paid as Payment
FROM Tab_Purchase a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tab_Payments b ON a.Comp_ID = b.Comp_ID AND a.Date = b.Date
WHERE a.Comp_ID = "C1"
UNION
SELECT b.Date, a.Gross, a.Net, a.Bonus, b.Paid as Payment
FROM Tab_Payments b
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tab_Purchase a ON a.Comp_ID = b.Comp_ID AND a.Date = b.Date
WHERE b.Comp_ID = "C1"
```

Comment: one more doubt.. how to modify the sql query,if i want company name also in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here we get the requred details of the company named 'Company1' in each date.I believe this will help you

Try this query:

```
select p.Date as Date,p.Gross as Gross,p.Net as Net,p.Bonus as Bonus,p1.Paid as Payment 
from Tab_Purchase p,Tab_Payments p1 
where (p.Comp_Id=(select c.Comp_Id 
from Tab_Comp c 
where Comp_Name='Company1')) 
and (p.Date=p1.Date)
```

Comment: Format your post please. Also provide a minimal explanation of what it does.